# Problems after installation of TYPO3 extension pits_downloadcenter

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I'm using TYPO3 9.5.5 and have installed pits_downloadcenter 3.0.1 extension.
I am encountering errors after installation in 'Extensions Manager'.

> Call to a member function admin_get_tables() on null"
>   in "typo3conf/ext/pits_downloadcenter/class.ext_update.php line 68"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the extension "[TYPO3_DB compatibility layer for TYPO3 v9.x](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/typo3db_legacy/)" installed? It seems that the extension pits_downloadcenter still relies on the deprecated database functionality.

You should report this issue in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/hojaonline/pits_downloadcenter/issues) of the extension.

Comment: I installed the extension "typo3db_legacy" that you mentioned and everything went well.
I'll report the issue as you suggested.
Thanks for your help.